# Powershell calling Powershell script

Tags: powershell

How does the behaviour differ between `& powershell .\other.ps1` and `& .\other.ps1`?

Edit: In particular, how do they differ if there's an error in `other.ps1`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get another PowerShell process in the former case and the script cannot read variables defined in your current session:

```
PS> $foo = 'bar'
PS> 'Write-Host $foo'|Set-Content x.ps1
PS> & powershell .\x.ps1

PS> & .\x.ps1
bar
```

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Just like variables, exceptions will not cross process boundaries. Change the contents of `x.ps1` to `throw error`, and compare the output of `try { powershell.exe ./x.ps1; "success? $?; $LastExitCode" } catch { "caught $_; success? $?; $LastExitCode" }` and `try { ./x.ps1; "success? $?; $LastExitCode" } catch { "caught $_; success? $?; $LastExitCode" }`.